# Toast appearing on Bottom even though Gravity is set to TOP|LEFT

Tags: android, android-toast, android-api-levels

Here is all the code related to the Toast (it's within the *mainActivity*). The main (and only) layout is a *LinearLayout* although I don't think that's relevant since it's **not** a custom toast.

```
Toast taux = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
taux.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
taux.show();
```

Thing is, doesn't matter if I set gravity to any other option (combining two like in the code or with just a single one) it will still appear only on te bottom centered (default position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int))

> Warning: Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#R, for apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R or higher, this method is a no-op when called on text toasts.

[Snackbar is recommended](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast)

> Note that Snackbars are preferred for brief messages while the app is in the foreground.

Toast.setGravity() can no longer do the work in API 30+ and it is recommended to use Snackbar instead to replace Toast if you're app is in the foreground.

Comment: Thanks! Will try to do that and mark your answer as the correct one if everything works fine.